# Multiplying calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple calculator that takes a number from 1 text box and after hitting a submit button it takes the number and multiplies it by 92 then puts it in a read only box.
This is what I have so far:

```
<form name="1star">

<input type="text" name="input"/>

<input type="button" value="Enter" OnClick="1star.output.value == 1star.input.value *   92"/>

<br/>
<input type="text" name="output" readonly="readonly" />    
</form>
```

This is not working and I could use some help. I know its easy but I am very new to js and I'm not understanding why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form name="onestar">

<input type="text" name="input"/>

<input type="button" value="Enter" OnClick="onestar.output.value = onestar.input.value *   92"/>

<br/>
<input type="text" name="output" readonly="readonly" />    
</form>
```

An identifier cannot start with a digit in JavaScript, so `1star` is an error. Also, you wanted `=` (assignment), not `==` (comparison).

That said, there are a number of outdated or beginner practices above. If I was writing it, I would separate the script from the markup, and I'd use `document.getElementById` to fetch the element rather than relying on implicit variables defined by `name`. I would also explicitly parse the string into a number. But for now no need to worry about it too much. Even though the code seems much more complicated at first glance, it's all things that will make your life easier later, with bigger programs.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    output.value = value * 92;
  }
});
```

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" id="input"/>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Enter"/>
  <br/>

  <input type="text" id="output" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

Comment: Haha, didn't even think about that. Thanks for the help!